# Looking for a "Universal" Document viewer component/library

Tags: java, applet, viewer, plugins

I am looking for an Applet with similar functionality to the Oracle/Stellent OutsideIn ActiveX control or the Autonomy KeyView technology that act as a browser plug-in allowing the rendering/display of a large number of file formats (Word processing, spreadhseet, graphics, etc.) I currently use the Stellent solution, but due to some restrictions of some of our clients would prefer something that either exists as a Java Applet, Silverlight control, or has a Java API that I could build an applet on top of (neither of the two I mentioned do).

> At a bare minimum it would need to display at least the following formats:
>
> > MS Word, Excel, PowerPoint
> >
> > MS Outlook MSG files
> >
> > Adobe PDF
> >
> > Standard image formats: BMP, PNG, JPEG, TIFF
> >
> > WordPerfect
> >
> > HTML

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a commercial product is an option, [ViewOne](http://www.daeja.com/products/viewone1.asp) is a nice product. It's an Applet and you can view a large variety of document.

Comment: I found this one shortly after I posted the question and am looking into it. Do you have any experience using it? Any commentary on it?

Comment: Yes, we are using it in one project to view TIF file and it's working fine.  You can add notes, allow printing or saving, etc. It also supports viewing of MSOffice documents like XLS or MSG.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a plugin, but [multivalent](http://multivalent.sourceforge.net/) is a java library and browser for a large number of document formats, but probably not all the ones you'd like to cover.

It does at least cover the PDF, HTML, and any reasonable image format, but not any of the proprietary formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pure Java component that supports all these formats, I'm pretty confident that it doesn't exist. If what you want is to embed Browser, MS Office, Acrobat etc. you would need an ActiveX container.

Here are some choices:

[JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net/#demos) - if you are using Swing (see the Document Viewer demo.)

[SWT ActiveX container](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/swtactivexcontainer) - if you are using SWT

[TeamDev WinPack](http://www.teamdev.com/winpack/demo.jsf) - if your time is more valuable than your money ;-) The product is very polished, the price is reasonable and the support is excellent.

Note that with any of these you need to have installed Acrobat, MS Office (or the free doc viewers) and whatever else applications you need to edit the file formats.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Adeptol AJAX Document Viewer.
A no plugin non applet no install viewer which supports more than 300 file typess.
See [ajaxdocumentviewer.com](http://www.ajaxdocumentviewer.com)

Comment: This is a duplicate of another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in Net-it Central. It uses an Active-x plugin or java applet and works with several different formats. I am using it for Word and Excel currently.